# How do I split an IplImage into HSV channels using JavaCV Libraries

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to track a bright point (laser pointer) using JavaCV, but I am having trouble figuring out how to split an Image or IplImage into HSV Channels to track this point.

Answer (score 2):

To give a more clear answer:

```
IplImage orgImg = cvLoadImage( ... );

IplImage hsv = IplImage.create( orgImg.width(), orgImg.height(), orgImg.depth(), orgImg.nChannels() );
IplImage hue = IplImage.create( orgImg.width(), orgImg.height(), orgImg.depth(), CV_8UC1 );
IplImage sat = IplImage.create( orgImg.width(), orgImg.height(), orgImg.depth(), CV_8UC1 );
IplImage val = IplImage.create( orgImg.width(), orgImg.height(), orgImg.depth(), CV_8UC1 );

cvCvtColor( orgImg, hsv, CV_BGR2HLS );
cvSplit( hsv, hue, sat, val, null );
```